# BQL Group By In Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How can I translate this SQL query:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value
```

to Acumatica BQL?

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no Having function available in Bql yet.

The way I have solved this is with projections to generate sub-queries. For example:

```
[Serializable]
[PXProjection(typeof(
    Select4<Table,
        Aggregate<
            GroupBy<Table.column1,
            Sum<Table.column2>>>>))]
public class AggregateTable : IBqlTable
{
    // This will contain aggregate value - GroupBy
    public abstract class column1: PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }

    [PXDBString(BqlField = typeof(Table.column1))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Column1")]
    public virtual string Column1 { get; set; }

    // This will contain aggregate value - Sum
    public abstract class column2: PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }

    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(Table.column2))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Column2")]
    public virtual int? Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can filter the  aggregate with a normal select:

```
public PXSelect<AggregateTable, Where<AggregateTable.column2, Equal<Required<AggregateTable.column2>>>> FilteredTable;

var rows = FilteredTable.Select(10);
```

I try to use this very sparingly because it can get messy if you are not careful.

Comment: Hi @vannak , Was this answer helpful?

Comment: Hi @vannak , it's been a while, but if you found this answer helpful, could you accept it as valid? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In FBQL appeared Having. Below goes example of AggregateTo<> and OrderBy<> sections with Having implemented:

```
.AggregateTo<Sum<field1>, GroupBy<field2>, Max<field3>,
     Min<field4>, Avg<field5>, Count<field6>>.
     Having<field5.Averaged.IsGreater<Zero>>
    .OrderBy<field1.Asc, field2.Desc, field3.Asc>
```